# ASCII characters is converted (appended) with arbitrary character in grails 3

Tags: grails, configuration, ascii

i am submitting a value "02AP0040¶" in my grails 3 application, when the form is submitted via ajax the value in the controller is not altered but when the form is submitted normally the value is changed to "**02AP0040Â¶**" **Â** is added. I have changed the mime types in application.yml,  **form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** to **form: multipart/form-data** Part of my configuration file (application.yml) is this :

```
grails:
applicationVersion: '@info.app.version@'
mime:
    disable:
        accept:
            header:
                userAgents:
                    - Gecko
                    - WebKit
                    - Presto
                    - Trident
    types:
        all: '*/*'
        atom: application/atom+xml
        css: text/css
        csv: text/csv
        form: multipart/form-data
        html:
          - text/html
          - application/xhtml+xml
        js: text/javascript
        json:
          - application/json
          - text/json
        multipartForm: multipart/form-data
        pdf: application/pdf
        rss: application/rss+xml
        text: text/plain
        hal:
          - application/hal+json
          - application/hal+xml
        xml:
          - text/xml
          - application/xml
    file.extensions: true
    use.accept.header: false
urlmapping:
    cache:
        maxsize: 1000
controllers:
    upload:
        maxFileSize: 2097152 #2MB
        maxRequestSize: 2097152 #2MB
    defaultScope: prototype
converters:
    encoding: UTF-8
views:
    default:
        codec: none
    gsp:
        encoding: UTF-8
        htmlcodec: xml
        codecs:
            expression: none
            scriptlets: html
            taglib: none
            staticparts: none
```

The submitting form is also submitting the correct value to the controller but when it comes to the controller the value is altered.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution might not be the perfect one but solved my problem.

I have added enctype attribute as `<form action="" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>` to each form that submits such ascii characters. I tried to change the mime type in application.yml but it didn't work so i used javascript in my main page to add the enctype to every form which currently solved the issue.

What i found was, even though the method is post, the default form enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded which treats the request body as queryparameters and hence encode/escape the ascii characters so for to transfer these kind of characters we have to use enctype as multipart/form-data which doesn't encode the content.